# Is there any difference between java script if/else and c++ if/else?

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, break

I was wondering that is the if/else statements in js different or the same as c++.I have worked in c++ and the if/else conditions work as automatically break is put in that if one condition is true the other doesn't work but in js, the conditions were printed again and again.even though the item is found the else part is shown in the next iteration

```
var A = ["cake","apple pie","cookie","chips","patties"];
var search=prompt("Welcome to ABC Bakery.What do you want to order Sir/Ma'm");
var size=A.length;
for(var i=0;i<=size;i++)
{
    if(search===A[i])
    {
        alert(search+" is available at index "+(i+1)+" of our bakery");
        check=true;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("We are sorry "+search  +" is not available in our bakery");
    }
}
```

Comment: They are functionally the same and sever the same purpose. However, they all accept _different values_ for “truthy” and “not truthy”. Likewise, comparison operators/behavior feeding these expressions vary greatly. A **bug in code** is, well, not really related to another language: use the one you have. (So practice writing relevantly focused and less hubristic titles..)

Comment: Also, in context the “break” applies to the “for”, and has nothing to do with the “if” directly. This is also works generally the same between those languages (some also support labels).

Comment: @user2864740 Thank you for your help.I have came to know  my problem.It means that if/else is same in both of these

Comment: @user2864740 Respectfully asking Should I delete my post now If I have found the problem

Comment: It doesn’t make a difference to me. Good job finding the problem.

Answer (score 1):

C++ and JS have very different tastes in foods, which is why you might be experiencing oddness in your if/else statements. I have found that C++ tends to stick with the staples like bread, eggs, and oysters, whereas js prefers more exotic foods like almond butter.

In your case, though, I'm not convinced that the food has anything to do with the problem you are seeing. The `break` keyword functions similarly in both languages. Without knowing what food you are requesting, it is not possible for me to know what you're seeing versus what you would expect, but my guess is that when you enter a food that exists in `A` but is not the first food (in this case cake, which you should avoid except for special occasions but I'm not a licensed nutritionist so take that with a pinch of salt), then you are seeing a number of "We are sorry..." messages followed by the "...is available..." message. That is because you are looping over the elements of `A`, and are triggering the `else` statement each time, until the `if` statement is finally true and your `break` is triggered.

Instead what you want is to check if the food is really in the store at all, and in that case get its index. Otherwise I'd recommend placing an order with your distributor because it sounds like your customers are really clamoring for it and you don't want a riot on your hands. I think we all learned that from the great Toilet Paper Fiasco of April 2020. As a foodie myself, here's what I would do instead of your loop.

```
var index = A.indexOf(search);
if (index > -1) {
    alert(search+" is available at index "+(index+1)+" of our bakery");
    check=true;
}
else {
    alert("We are sorry "+search  +" is not available in our bakery");
}
```

Comment: @Banamagrammer.Does the code you have mentioned works